# Cannot install pandasql in Spyder/Anaconda

Tags: python, pandas, module, pandasql

So I am kind of new to Python, and for the life  of me I cannot figure this out. I am using spyder with anaconda and this specific module, pandasql, I am unable to locate. I go to the environment search tab and cannot find it. I downloaded the most recent versions of each program so I am unsure what else I can do at this point. Any help would be appreciated!

```
 from pandasql import sqldf

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandasql'
```

Comment: I'm assuming you already installed it into the correct python environment using the command `pip install pandasql`, right?

Comment: Yes! Well I think so. I opened the Anaconda prompt and used pip install pandasql, but it came out to an error saying no matching distribution found for pandsql.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured it out! I needed to use the command prompt from the Anaconda Navigator specifically.